# Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now

Tags: java, android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':laMusique2May2016:javaPreCompileRelease'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - auto-value-1.1.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1)
  Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
  See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

I am seeing this issue, but the problem is auto-value-1.1.jar is not in my gradle files

Comment: So did you read the sentence that starts *Alternatively*?

Comment: @KenWhite Whiteyes it says at the end " Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future" Did you read that part?

Comment: "but the problem is auto-value-1.1.jar is not in my gradle files" -- if you are saying that you do not have `com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1` in your dependencies, then that is coming from a transitive dependency. Try to track down which of your dependencies is itself depending on `auto-value`, then contact the developers of that dependency and ask about what to do. And, temporarily, consider that workaround cited in the error and in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should explicitly add annotation processors in gradle. Putting the following in your gradle dependencies should fix it:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1'
```

---

However, as others have already mentioned, you should probably figure out which of your existing dependencies was using auto-value to assert whether or not you really need it. Annotation processors ultimately slow down your build time so don't include it if it's unnecessary.

Comment: it's bit older but I'm facing similar issue. I have java annotation processor and using it in a project with java and kotlin classes. Before Kotlin was introduced it worked with: 
```
compileOnly project(':annotation-processor')
annotationProcessor project(':annotation-processor')
```

After Kotlin the `annotationProcessor` didn't picked up kotlin files so I switched to kapt. But then I got `Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now` error. With both `kapt` and `annotationProcessor` it seems to work but it looks weird. Kapt should pick up Java as well. So why the error?

Comment: This answer actually explain what you should replace, not just add to your gradle file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55823353/413127

Answer (score 34):

Even i had the same problem and finally i solved my problem by adding this to app level gradle file

```
android{
....
    defaultConfig{
....
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
...
}
```

hope its solved someone's problem

Comment: This fixed mine.

Comment: this is the deprecated behaviour though, this will be removed in a year or so likely...

Comment: **deprecated, don't use**

Answer (score 4):

Adding annotationProcessor dependencies not work for me, instead I drop this line inside `build.gradle` at arbitrary places works:

`android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true`

Comment: @BenMorris-Rains just put this line anywhere in `build.gradle` but outside any scope. or see the answer below.

Comment: @wdanxna Thank you! I actually pinned the problem down to trying to use firebase firestore and switched over to real time database instead, which works without any problems. 

I'll refer to this if I try to use firestore again.

Comment: this is the deprecated behaviour though, this will be removed in a year or so likely...

Comment: **deprecated, don't use**

Answer (score 3):

Annotation processors can be **declared** with `annotationProcessor` **instead of** `implementation/compile` like we used to declare earlier.

```
implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1' 

compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1'
```

**Should be replaced with**

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue happened because `jitpack` wasn't placed as the last entry in root grade.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ... other repositories
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

The solution was taken from @hotchemi comment in https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/535#issuecomment-432190926