# Annotation Processors Must Be Explicitly Decalred Now

Tags: android, annotations, android-glide

I added following libraries in my Android After that I'm getting error.

- https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/download/v4.6.1/compiler-4.6.1.jar
- https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/download/v4.6.1/glide-full-4.6.1.jar

**Error:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - compiler-4.6.1.jar (compiler-4.6.1.jar)   Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath
= true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.   See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usamaakmal.bookswap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101341/error-annotation-processors-must-be-explicitly-declared-now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Annotation Processors must be explicitly declared now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101341/error-annotation-processors-must-be-explicitly-declared-now)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Library has some kind of issue so I decide [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
 against it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to use glide as a jar library.

just use it's dependency...

in project-> build.gradle file :

Add this code.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

In App build.gradle file:
Add this code.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I removes these (jar) still same error and tried your method both are not working

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when trying to use glide. 
If you are using Kotlin. You should add this

```
dependencies {
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

check the instructions here http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#gradle

Answer (score 0):

Just read the setup instructions and follow them (use `implementation` instead of `compile` if your Gradle version allows it):
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html#gradle

Also make sure you delete any local copies of Glide .jar files in the `libs` folder. I have a feeling https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080598/253468 didn't work because you were still using the original problematic way of consuming the library; in general for Android you shouldn't have to use the `libs` folder, the ecosystem is mature enough to have jcenter/mavenCentral published libraries.

Answer (score -1):

In App build.gradle file :Add this code:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
       ...
       javaCompileOptions { annotationProcessorOptions { includeCompileClasspath = true } }
    }
}
```

Comment: This option is deprecated and will be removed in the future